# Razor - Umbraco: Check if image exists

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

I am trying to display images in umbraco using razor, but at the moment if I dont upload an image then an empty image is displayed, is there a way around this? I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
if (media.Id != 0)
{
   <img src="@page.Media("img","umbracoFile")" alt="" />
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use the following:

```
var image = Model.MediaById(Model.Image);

string imagePath = "/default-image-path.gif";
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(image.UmbracoFile))
{
    imagePath = image.UmbracoFile;
}

<img src="@imagePath " />
```

The good thing about this is that you can specify a default image. Or:

```
var image = Model.MediaById(Model.Image);
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(image.UmbracoFile))
{
    <img src="@image.UmbracoFile" />
}
```

put your img tag in the conditional statement to hide it if there is no image available.